# .net Setup project force new file replacement on reinstall

Tags: .net, installation, versioning, windows

I have a setup project that install a couple of projects and a couple of external files (one of which is a SQLite Database) - everything worked fine until i've recently modified the base database file included in the setup project.

Now, everytime i try to reinstall the project the new database file does not replace the previously installed one... Can i force it somehow in VS or make the setup realize this is a new version so the file gets replaced?

Best Regards,

Carlos Ouro

Comment: Is the DB part of the Setup project itself, or how are you making it get installed? (It could be a "content" in one of your projects tied to the setup project)

Comment: I've added it to the project via right click -> Add -> File...
I've tried removing it and adding it again but it still doesn't replace the previous installed file.

Comment: it should read *added it to the setup project*

Comment: I've tried to uninstall it, rebooted the machine, change the version in the setup project and reinstall it and it still does not change the file...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One month and a few days later...
So it turns out that there is no way to do this to a file added directly in the Deployment project in VS2008 (used to be possible in VS2005...).

But after many many attempts i finally figured out a decent workaround.

- I've included the file "Database.sqlite" directly in a windows forms project (Database) with the following properties: "Build Action -> Content file" and "Copy to Output Directory -> Copy always"
- Then i added it to the deployment project via Project Output->Database->Content Files

Now apparently everything works fine and the file gets replaced every time i change it and rebuild the deployment project.

This one put up quite a fight ^^